# Proving a special case of the Squeeze Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove that if $\{a_n\}\to0$, $$0\leqslant b_n\leqslant a_n \implies \{b_n\}\to0,$$where $a_n,b_n$ are infinite sequences and $n\in\mathbb{N}$.  Then, using the result $$\{a_n\}\to0\iff\{\left|a_n\right|\}\to0,$$prove that  if $\{a_n\}\to0$, $$0\leqslant \left|b_n\right|\leqslant a_n \implies \{b_n\}\to0$$

**My Attempt**

We begin by proving that if $\{a_n\}\to0$, $$0\leqslant b_n\leqslant a_n \implies \{b_n\}\to0.$$
So we have
$$\{a_n\}\to0\iff\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists N\in \mathbb{N}\text{ s.t. }\left|a_n\right|<\epsilon \forall n>N.$$Now $$0\leqslant b_n\leqslant a_n \implies  \left|b_n\right|\leqslant\left|a_n\right|$$and so$$\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists N\in \mathbb{N}\text{ s.t. }\left|b_n\right|\leqslant\left|a_n\right|<\epsilon \forall n>N\\\implies\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists N\in \mathbb{N}\text{ s.t. }\left|b_n\right|<\epsilon \forall n>N\\\iff \{b_n\}\to 0.$$
Now using the given result, we obtain that $\{\left|b_n\right|\}\to0$. After this point I am stuck so any hints will be appreciated.

---

What really confuses me about this question is that you can prove that if $\{a_n\}\to0$, $$0\leqslant \left|b_n\right|\leqslant a_n \implies \{b_n\}\to0$$ in a different order of the steps than the question requires. If you just write down the definition for $\{a_n\}$ being a null sequence and then use the fact that $0\leqslant \left|b_n\right|\leqslant a_n \implies \left|b_n\right|\leqslant\left|a_n\right|$ (since $\left|a_n\right|=a_n\geqslant0$) you can prove that $\{\left|b_n\right|\}\to 0$ and then using the given result it follows that $\{b_n\}\to 0$.

Again, any help will be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

1) If $\{a_n\}\to0$, $0\leqslant b_n\leqslant a_n \implies \{b_n\}\to0$

2) $\{a_n\}\to0\iff\{\left|a_n\right|\}\to0$

so from (1), by replacing $b_n$ by $|b_n|$

3)  If $\{a_n\}\to0$, $0\leqslant |b_n| \leqslant a_n \implies \{|b_n|\}\to0$

and from (2), by replacing $a_n$ by $b_n$

4) $\{b_n\}\to0\iff\{\left|b_n\right|\}\to0$

and combining (3) and (4)

5) If $\{a_n\}\to0$, $0\leqslant |b_n| \leqslant a_n \implies \{b_n\}\to0$

*quod erat demonstrandum*.

Comment: But wouldn't be valid only if the sequence $b_n$ is positive? What if it is negative?

Comment: $b_n$ is positive in (1) and $|b_n|$ is positive in (3), (4) and (5), but $b_n$ need not be positive in (4) and this allows you to make the desired conclusion in (5) even if $b_n$ is not positive